# How to enable the component generated HTML/CSS in wicket

Tags: html, css, menu, wicket, treemodel

I have tried the Tree based menu in wicket ,

I  have used the same code as mentioned below link to create a menu.

http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/nested/?0

While deploying the same code into our server ,

The +,- symbol is not loaded,When i check in console, I am to see the code for +,- symbol but corresponding code and css is disabled.

So  html is rendered but disabled ,
for example I am able to see below html code in console but disabled(to show minus in menu)

```
<span class="minus"></span>
```

can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean with disabled? You see it but you cannot click it? You might check if CSS for Tree component is correctly fetched by browser.

Comment: I am not even able to see the html fields but able the fields in console with a disabled state.. So fields are disabled in console (f12) which is not visible in browser

Comment: Ah ok, you are referring to Chrome console. I think the problem might be caused by some of your custom CSS. I've tried the code from the example and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by  moving all tree related CSS into local form wicket.extensions.jar